# Python: como servir uma página HTML programaticamente sem travar a execução

Tags: python, http, localhost

Eu sei que é possível criar um servidor local em Python digitando na CLI `python -m http.server`. Posso também executar este comando de dentro de um *script* Python usando `os.system`. O problema é que isto trava a execução. Tem alguma maneira de servir uma página e permitir a continuação do programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente se usa Flask ou Django para essas finalidades, mas se for algo assim simples dá para fazer só usando *threads*:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread

PORT = 8000  # pode escolher qualquer uma
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
server_thread = Thread(target=localhost_server.serve_forever).start()
```

A última linha vai iniciar o *host* imediatamente e o código que estiver em sequência será executado logo após da inicialização do servidor. `server_forever` trancaria a execução se não fosse posto numa *thread*.

Importante destacar que isto vai servir o conteúdo que está no *working directory* da execução atual. Normalmente este diretório é o mesmo em que está o arquivo Python que foi executado, mas há casos em que uma IDE pode interferir nele. Você pode descobrir o *working directory* usando `os.getcwd()` e alterá-lo usando `os.chdir(diretorio)`, tendo em mente que ele não deverá ser alterado novamente enquanto durar o servidor. Para encerrar o servidor, basta executar `server.shutdown()`.